# Php create file and change location doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have another php question, but now when i click the register button it doesnt run the ajax request, it's just refreshing

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
    position: relative;
}


.container {
    padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
    -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
    animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)} 
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
       display: block;
       float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
<body>



<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="id01" class="modal">

  <form class="modal-content animate" >
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Username" id="uname" name="uname" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" value="" placeholder="Enter Password" id="uname" name="psw" required>

      <button onclick="login();" >Register</button>

    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function login(){

$.ajax ({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'register.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    us: document.getElementById('uname').value,
    ps: document.getElementById('psw').value
  },
  success: function(data){
    if (data && data.success && data.redirect_url) {
      window.location.href = data.redirect_url;
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      alert('failed! see browser console for returned data!');
    }
  },
  fail: function(data){
    alert('Failed');
  }
});
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is php code for creating file and change location in urlbar:

```
<?php
// get username and password
$username = $_POST['us'];
 $password = $_POST['ps'];
$file = fopen($username + '.' + $password, 'w');
// Here we need to create the sha1 hash as crypto-address
$crypto_address = sha1($username + $password);
// Write crypto address to file
fwrite($file, $crypto_address);
fclose($file);
// you want do have some validation here propably instead of assinging true 
to is_valid:
$is_valid = true;

if ($is_valid) {
echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'redirect_url' => 'user.php']);
die();
 }
 echo json_encode(['success' => false]);
 ?>
```

So why it doesn't work?

Regards,
Christian

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but based on what I've guessed : your header is executed on your Ajax request not on the user ones. Look at your dev tools, the ajax request must be redirected

Comment: I didnt get what u mean i think u mean i should change location in javascript or what

Comment: Your `header('Location: ...)` is called in a code called via Ajax. So only the Ajax request can be redirected. If you want to redirect user you have to do it in your `success callback`

Comment: Extending what @NicolasPerraut said - add a location.href = "user.php" in the success callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the redirection client side, ie in your javascript callback :

```
success: function(data){
   location.href = 'user.php'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will not redirect (location in urlbar will not update) because you perform an AJAX call, and not a form POST request. So, do this in JS:

```
$.ajax ({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'register.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    us: document.getElementByName('uname').value,
    ps: document.getElementByName('psw').value
  },
  success: function(data){
    if (data && data.success && data.redirect_url) {
      window.location.href = data.redirect_url;
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      alert('failed! see browser console for returned data!');
    }
  },
  fail: function(data){
    alert('Failed');
  }
});
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
  // get username and password
  $username = $_POST['us'];
  $password = $_POST['ps'];
  $file = fopen($username + '.' + $password, 'w');
  // Here we need to create the sha1 hash as crypto-address
  $crypto_address = sha1($username + $password);
  // Write crypto address to file
  fwrite($file, $crypto_address);
  fclose($file);
  // you want do have some validation here propably instead of assinging true to is_valid:
  $is_valid = true;

  if ($is_valid) {
    echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'redirect_url' => 'user.php']);
    die();
  }
  echo json_encode(['success' => false]);
```

If the file was not created, we will need more info to come to a solution here, can you answer this?:

- Any errors in your apache logs? (The folder you are trying to write a file to may not be writable by the user that executes the PHP at your webserver)
- What is the response from the AJAX call? (visible in your browser debuggers 'network' tab):

  - 500: something wrong with your PHP code
  - 404: your PHP script might never be executed because you are using the wrong URL
  - 302 / 301: your script worked, your PHP should be OK

Comment: another question have nothing to do with this but maybe u know some good php hosting service free because last 4 suspended me for unknown reason after 5 minutes

Comment: Now it just refreshing site without even run the request, have updated the code below

Comment: try adding an id to the button instead and remove the inline 

onclick="login();"

then do document.getElementById('<id from button>').onclick = function () { >AJAX CALL HERE> }